# linkedin to dynamics crm integration

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get a popup in Dynamics CRM (2011) with information about the account from LinkedIn, as seen here http://www.alticoadvisors.com/Portals/0/Adding%20LinkedIn%20to%20Dynamics%20CRM%20-%20Aug2010%20CRM%20Tip.pdf

I have attached a field to the form which should change to a button with the form's onLoad function. This worked with a simple piece of javascript in the `FunctionName` e.g. an alert, however when I tried to add the more complicated script with the Linked In integration, I get a blank window open in Internet Explorer and the button doesn't change.

I'm afraid I'm quite new the javacript and I can't see where the mistake is. My other fear is that the Linked In part was written for CRM 4.0 and I'm using 2011, but I don't know the differences in the entities to spot and correct any mistake.

Below is my javascript in the web resource. Any thoughts or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

```
function open()
{
ConvertToButton('new_buttonfield', 'LinkedIn','100px',FunctionName,'Button Label'); 
}

function ConvertToButton(fieldname, buttontext, buttonwidth,clickevent, title)
{

 //check if object exists; else return
 if (document.getElementById(fieldname) == null)
{
    alert("no field by that name");
    return;
 }


 functiontocall=clickevent;
 crmForm.all[fieldname].DataValue = buttontext;
 crmForm.all[fieldname].readOnly = true;
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.borderRight="#3366cc 1px solid";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.paddingRight="5px";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.borderTop="#3366cc 1px solid";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.paddingLeft="5px";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.fontSize="11px";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.backgroundImage="url(/_imgs/btn_rest.gif)";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.borderLeft="#3366cc 1px solid";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.width=buttonwidth;
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.cursor="hand";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.lineHeight="18px";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.borderBottom="#3366cc 1px solid";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.backgroundRepeat="repeat-x";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.fontFamily="Tahoma";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.height="20px";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.backgroundColor="#cee7ff";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.textAlign="center";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.overflow="hidden";
 crmForm.all[fieldname].attachEvent("onmousedown",push_button);
 crmForm.all[fieldname].attachEvent("onmouseup",release_button);
 crmForm.all[fieldname].attachEvent("onclick",functiontocall);
 crmForm.all[fieldname].style.lineHeight="14px";
 crmForm.all[fieldname+'_c'].style.visibility = 'hidden';
 crmForm.all[fieldname].title=title;
 window.focus();

}

 function push_button(){
 window.event.srcElement.style.borderWidth="2px";
 window.event.srcElement.style.borderStyle="groove ridge ridge groove";
     window.event.srcElement.style.borderColor="#3366cc #4080f0 #4080f0 #3366cc";
 }

 function release_button(){
 window.event.srcElement.style.border="1px solid #3366cc";
 }


 function LinkedInLoader(crmFormField) {

     var ll = this;
     ll.scriptSource = 'http://www.linkedin.com/companyInsider?script&useBorder=yes'
     ll.field = crmFormField;
     ll.container = crmFormField.parentNode;
     ll.nameToSearch = crmFormField.DataValue;
     ll.spanId = ll.field.id + '_linkedin';
     if (ll.container != null) {
         var span = document.createElement('span');
         span.id = ll.field.id + '_linkedin';
         var td1 = document.createElement('td');
         td1.innerHTML = ll.container.innerHTML;
         var td2 = document.createElement('td');
         td2.appendChild(span);
         td2.style.width = '15px';
         var tr = document.createElement('tr');
             tr.appendChild(td1);
         tr.appendChild(td2);
         var table = document.createElement('table');
         table.width = '100%';
         table.style.tableLayout = 'fixed';
         table.cellSpacing = 0;
             table.cellPading = 0;
         table.appendChild(tr);
         ll.container.innerHTML = table.outerHTML;
     }

     ll.ApplyCorrections = function () {
         var div = document.getElementById('company-insider-info-window');
         if (div != null) div.style.height = '275px';
         else window.setTimeout(ll.ApplyCorrections, 500);
     }

     ll.Enable = function () {
         new LinkedIn.CompanyInsiderPopup(ll.spanId, ll.nameToSearch);
         new LinkedIn.CompanyInsiderStylesheet();
         var span = document.getElementById(ll.spanId);
         if (span != null) span.attachEvent('onclick', ll.ApplyCorrections);
     }

     ll.OnScriptReadyState = function () {
         if ((event.srcElement.readyState == 'complete') ||
    (event.srcElement.readyState == 'loaded')) {
             ll.Enable();
         }
     }

     ll.Load = function () {
         var script = document.createElement('script');
         script.type = 'text/javascript';
             script.src = ll.scriptSource;
         script.onreadystatechange = ll.OnScriptReadyState;
         document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
         }
 }

// now the definition of the function to call on button click
function FunctionName()
{
//if (account.FormType != 1) {
    // Set the field that contains the company name
    var linkedInLoader = new LinkedInLoader(crmForm.all.name);
    linkedInLoader.Load();
    //}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at this, there are several things...

First, the LinkedIn URL you are dynamically injecting is HTTP and not HTTPS.  It also looks like the URL generates a Syntax error when switching it to HTTPS.

Your best bet is to use the API provided from LinkedIn: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api

Lastly, the Company Profile you're referencing has been deprecated.  Here's the most recent version of what you're trying to do: http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/jsapi-console/#examples/company_profile/hover.html&{"framework":"platform.linkedin.com/in.js","frameworkurl":"","apikey":"","apioptions":"","sessionbuttons":true,"async":false}